# Unable to pod install cocoapod master repos into swift project

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

I am not able to do a `pod install`command when I transferred my swift project to another MacBook pro that I have got. I have done a `pod disintegrate` into my project folder.

Since two days ago I have been trying to do a `pod install`, but was able to do a `pod init`. I am prompted with this error msg:

> Unable to add source with url 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' named 'master'.
>   You can try adding it manually in '~/.cocoapods/repos' or via 'pod repo add'.

I have tried the method proposed but I was still not able to install Firebase/Core.

I would like to also know if I should delete away any of the related pod files after I transferred my project to a new terminal?

Side story: 
The project was created in an iMac with OS Yosemite. The Macbook Pro I am using now is EI Captain. Does it matter?

Thank you!

**Solution:
Hi all, 
My issue was due to my wifi connection. Everything works fine after I am in a place with strong wifi.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `pod setup` command. That will setup things for you.

after that try `pod install`

Comment: Done! My issue lies with my wifi connection.